# Grails Error for using e-mail service

Tags: grails, groovy, controller, service, email

This is the controller

> class JavaMailerController {
>
> ```
> JavaMailerService javamailerservice
> def x = {javamailerservice.serviceMethod()} }
> ```

This is the Service

> import javax.mail.*; import
>   javax.mail.internet.*; import
>   java.util.*;
>
> class JavaMailerService {
>
> ```
> boolean transactional = false
>
> def serviceMethod() { String  d_email = "thisemail@gmail.com",
>         d_password = "thispassword",
>         d_host = "smtp.gmail.com",
>         d_port  = "587",
>         m_to = "thisto@gmail.com",
>         m_subject = "Testing",
>         m_text = "Hey, this is the testing email.";
>
>     Properties props = new Properties();
>     props.put("mail.smtp.user", d_email);
>     props.put("mail.smtp.host", d_host);
>     props.put("mail.smtp.port", d_port);
>     props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");
> ```
>
> // just in case, but not currently
>   necessary, oddly enough
>           props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
>           //props.put("mail.smtp.debug", "true");
>           props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port",
>   d_port);
>           props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
>   "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
>           props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback",
>   "false");
>
> ```
>     SecurityManager security = System.getSecurityManager();
>
>     try
>     {
>         Authenticator auth = new SMTPAuthenticator();
>         Session session = Session.getInstance(props, auth);
>         //session.setDebug(true);
>
>         MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
>         msg.setText(m_text);
>         msg.setSubject(m_subject);
>         msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(d_email));
>         msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
> ```
>
> new InternetAddress(m_to));
>               Transport.send(msg);
>           }
>           catch (Exception mex)
>           {
>               mex.printStackTrace();
>           }
>       }
>
> }
>
> private class SMTPAuthenticator
>   extends javax.mail.Authenticator
>       {
>           public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication()
>           {
>               return new PasswordAuthentication(d_email,
>   d_password);
>           }
>       }

The Error

Error 200: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method serviceMethod() on null object
Servlet: grails
URI: /JavaMailer/grails/javaMailer/x.dispatch
Exception Message: Cannot invoke method serviceMethod() on null object
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method serviceMethod() on null object
Class: Unknown
At Line: [-1]
Code Snippet:

Answer (score 2):

I think you didn't camelCase your service field in the controller.

```
class JavaMailerController {
   JavaMailerService javaMailerService
   def x = {
      javaMailerService.serviceMethod()
   } 
}
```